# assign colors to each level of factors in R figures

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I have a data set with one column which is a factor variable with 4 levels: `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. I used this codes to assign each level with a different color:

```
colorset = c('red', 'blue', 'green', 'black')
ggplot(...) + geom_density() + scale_fill_manual(values=colorset)
```

The code works fine if the data set contains all 4 levels. But sometime the data set is missing one level, for example, missing `2`. Then the red is still for level `1`, but now blue is assigned to level `3`, and green for level `4`, while black is never used.

How do I change the code to make sure that, no matter what data set I use, the color assignment remain the same (like blue always for level `2`, green always for level `3` etc.)?

Comment: Any issues with this answer?

Comment: No. This is perfect! Thank you very much Mike.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
n <- 1000
A <- data.frame(id='A',x=rnorm(n, 5, 2))
B <- data.frame(id='B',x=rexp(n, 1/4))
C <- data.frame(id='C',x=rexp(n, 1/8))
D <- data.frame(id='D',x=rexp(n, 1/16))
df <- rbind(A,B,C,D)

colorset = c('B'='red','A'='green','D'='black','C'='blue'  )

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_density(aes(fill = id), alpha = .4, adjust = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=colorset) +
  scale_x_continuous( limits =c(0,40))
```

[image]